# An aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause is complex in nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I this example I need to get a list of percentages of jobs/tasks based on their priority:

```
Priority    Percentages
-----------------------
 1            %25
11            %10
```

`task_events` table is :

```
task_events_id  time    missing_info    job_id  task_index  machine_id  event_type  user    scheduling_class    priority    cpu_request memory_request  disk_space_request  different_machines_restriction
```

`job_id` and its task can be in multiple rows, so I create new column `task_events_id` as PK, that used in nested selection to get signal row for each job and task. Then apply this result to get the priority for each job. I came up with this query . The main concept here is that, I have 11 level of priority. Priority has many jobs. Each job is assigned to one priority.

```
Select 
    tes.[priority], (tes.total_priority * 100 / (select sum(tes.total_priority)from tes )) as [percentage]
From
    (select 
         [priority], count(*) as total_priority 
     from 
         task_events as t
     inner join
         (select 
              max(task_events_id) as maxid, 1 as total 
          from 
              task_events 
          group by 
              job_id, task_index) as te on t.task_events_id = te.maxid
     group by 
         [priority]) as tes 
group by 
    tes.[priority]
```

This the best I came up with, but the aggregate is the getting complex, any advice

With this query I got this error:

**Invalid object name 'tes'.**

while its wrong to put 'tes.total_priority'  on last group by.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.  For instance, percent of what?

Comment: of each job_id, each job here has priority, I have 11 level of priority, each priority has many jobs

Answer (score 0):

If, for each priority, you want its percent of the overall total, then use window functions:

```
select [priority], count(*) as total_priority,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from task_events t
group by [priority];
```

Comment: Okay, I just need the percent for job and task. so I believe it should be grouped by job.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your query is only need an additional field in last `group by` to work... add `tes.total_priority` there..
**It didn't work though - code removed**

```
-- Code removed
```

but you can consider this simpler query by removing `inner join` and use `distinct` instead

```
Select 
    tes.[priority], (tes.total_priority * 100.0 / sum(tes.total_priority)) as [percentage]
From
    (select
         [priority], count(*) as total_priority 
     from 
         (select  
             distinct [priority], job_id, task_index
         from task_events) as t
       ) as tes
group by 
    tes.[priority], tes.total_priority
```

or much more simpler one using window function

```
select 
    [priority], count(*) as total_priority,
    count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from (select distinct [priority], job_id, task_index
         from task_events) as t
group by [priority];
```

and the last one if `job_id` what you need to count and `task_index` can be removed from sub query.. then sub query can be removed by replacing `count(*)` with `count(distinct job_id)`.. but the result may be different from previous queries depend on data and which one is correct? that depend on what really want to achieve from that data.. its just suggestion though..

```
select 
    [priority], count(distinct job_id) as total_priority,
    count(distinct job_id) * 100.0 / sum(count(distinct job_id)) over () as ratio
from task_events t
group by [priority];
```

Comment: Ok, let see this one

Comment: if you add tes.total_priority, it will you give you 100 % for every priority. That's why I didn't add it on group by

Comment: and the last 2 queries have different answers, which make me worried which one might be the correct one.

Comment: OK, then the first query didn't work..(not like I originally though).. may be because of `100`, change it to `100.0`.. they should be give the same result except (may be) for the last query because `task_index` removed...

Comment: I might go with last one, but somehow my query should work, at least to check if am I getting right result

Comment: I add this on first selection                                                                     `Select tes.[priority], (tes.total_priority * 100 / select sum(tes.total_priority)from tes) as [percentage]`. To avoid the error that say tes.total_priority